# What are the differences comparing PIE, PIC code and executable on 64-bit x86 platform?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, x86, elf

The test is on Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. x86 architecture.

I am confused about the concept Position Independent Executable (PIE) and Position Independent code (PIC), and I guess they are not orthogonal.

Here is my quick experiment.

```
gcc -fPIC -pie quickSort.c -o a_pie.out
gcc -fPIC      quickSort.c -o a_pic.out
gcc                           a.out

objdump -Dr -j .text a.out > a1.temp
objdump -Dr -j .text a_pic.out > a2.temp
objdump -Dr -j .text a_pie.out > a3.temp
```

And I have the following findings.

**A.** a.out contains some PIC code, but **only** resists in the libc prologue and epilogue functions, as shown in below:

```
4004d0:       48 83 3d 70 09 20 00    cmpq   $0x0,0x200970(%rip)        # 600e48 <__JCR_END__>
```

In the assembly instructions of my simple quicksort program, I didn't find any PIC instructions.

**B.** a_pic.out contains PIC code, and I didn't find any **non-PIC** instructions... In the instructions of my quicksort program, all the global data are accessed by PIC instructions like this:

```
  40053b:       48 8d 05 ea 02 00 00    lea    0x2ea(%rip),%rax        # 40082c <_IO_stdin_used+0x4>
```

**C.** a_pie.out contains syntax-identical instructions comparing with a_pic.out. However, the memory addresses of a_pie.out's **.text** section range from 0x630 to 0xa57, while the same section of a_pic.out ranges from    0x400410 to 0x400817.

Could anyone give me some explanations of these phenomenons? Especially the finding **C**. Again, I am really confused about **PIE vs. PIC**, and have no idea how to explain the finding **C**..

Comment: Basically `PIE` is intended for executables and `PIC` for shared libraries. It doesn't make much sense to examine `PIC` executables. Also note that `gcc` invokes the linker accordingly.

Comment: `-fPIC -pie`  /facepalm.  You should have used the `-fPIE` code-gen option, not `-fPIC`.  `-pie` is a linker option that controls what kind of executable the code is actually put into.  (`-pie` alone would fail because it's incompatible with 32-bit absolute addressing).  See also [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](//stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about PIE executables vs. non-PIE.  (And note that most distros build GCC with `-fPIE -pie` being the default).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> I am confused about the concept Position Independent Executable (PIE) and Position Independent code (PIC), and I guess they are not orthogonal.

The only real difference between `PIE` and `PIC` is that you are allowed to *interpose* symbols in `PIC`, but not in `PIE`. Except for that, they are pretty much equivalent.

You can read about symbol interposition [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/building-library-interposers-for-fun-and/184404926).

> C. a_pie.out contains syntax-identical instructions comparing with a_pic.out. However, the memory addresses of a_pie.out's .text section range from 0x630 to 0xa57, while the same section of a_pic.out ranges from 0x400410 to 0x400817.

The `PIE` binary is linked just as a shared library, and so its default load address (the `.p_vaddr` of the first `LOAD` segment) is zero. The expectation is that something will relocate this binary away from zero page, and load it at some random address.

On the other hand, a non-`PIE` executable is *always* loaded at its linked-at address. On Linux, the default address for `x86_64` binaries is `0x400000`, and so the `.text` ends up not far from there.